# Android paint.SetStrokeWidth(0.5) i.e. less than 1 pixel

Tags: android

```
 paint.setStrokeWidth((float)0.5);
```

I have tried this But line is not visible at all.

Any help? Please.

Comment: If u want a very thin line then you can try `paint.setStrokeWidth(0);` which gives u a very small hairline as mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setStrokeWidth%28float%29).

Comment: paint.setStrokeWidh(0.5f)  result : Line is not visible

Comment: Passing 0 also didn't help

Comment: Then why not pass a bigger value if you wish to see a thicker line... Something like `paint.setStrokeWidth(3f or 4f or 5f...);`. The value inside is `width` of the stroke whenever the paint's style is Stroke or StrokeAndFill, so also check ur Paint.Style. Refer to the link I sent in the previous comment.

Comment: Sub-pixel drawing requires Anitaliasing, that's why you most probably cannot see it.

Comment: This will make it more bold line. I want it less than 1 pixel. by default this 1 pixel

Comment: @akuzma Your ansmer is correct, but i don't know how to implement.

Comment: Pixel is the smallest value of the screen and you cannot draw something thinner than that without anti-aliasing... Your best bet is use `0` which draws exactly 1 pixel irrespective to everything... Refer to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115244/drawing-line-less-than-one-pixel-thick-requires-anti-aliasing-in-android-4-2) for precise clarity...

Answer (score 1):

we have to pass zero for hairline mode.It will draw with one pixel

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Comment: ok abarisone.We have to pass zero for hairline mode.It will draw single pixel

Comment: Please don't use the comments to flesh out your answer. Edit your answer instead to add to it.